# My android app work android 3.0 and higher. But not work 2.3

Tags: android-layout, tabs, android-2.3-gingerbread, runtimeexception, android-listview

My application have Four tabs and each tabs works different activity. i fitting tabs with Program's mainactivity and the first tab get on the screen default. First tab show announcements with listview.. This apps work with Android 3.0 and higher but not work 2.3.3.
It'S force closed in mainactivity when add tabs.

```
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();     
    Log.w("mainactivity", "200 ");

    TabSpec tabspec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Duyurular");
    Log.w("mainactivity", "201 ");
    tabspec1.setIndicator("Duyuru");
    Log.w("mainactivity", "202 ");
    Intent tab1Intent = new Intent(this, duyurular.class);
    Log.w("mainactivity", "203 ");
    tabspec1.setContent(tab1Intent);
    Log.w("mainactivity", "204 ");
    tabHost.addTab(tabspec1); 
    Log.w("mainactivity", "205 ");
```

I see mainactivty  204 on LogCat but not see 205.

***MainActivty.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
static final int DIALOG_ERROR_CONNECTION = 1;
static final int YANLIS_VERI_GIRISI = 2;
static final int CIKIS_YAP = 3;
static final int ILETISIM = 4;
static final int Zorunlu_Kapat=5;
static String responseBody = null;
static String  rehberResponse=null;
static String  birimlerResponse=null;
static String   yemekresponseBody=null;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (isOnline(getApplicationContext())==true) 
    {

        Log.w("mainactivity", "100 ");
        TablariAyarla();

        final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();   
        setTabColor(tabHost);       // ilk sayfa gelince tab renkleri

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {   //tıklanınca tab renklerinin ayarlanması. 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int tab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
                setTabColor(tabHost);
            }
        });

    }
    }   

public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {       //seçili  tab arka plan rengi ayarı
    for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        Log.w("mainactivity", "300 ");
      //  tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B3A9A9")); //unselected
        tabhost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bttn_blue);
        TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv.setTextSize(8);
    }
    Log.w("mainactivity", "400 ");
 //   tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ee4000")); // selected
    tabhost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bttn_blue);
    TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv.setTextSize(8);   //tab başlığının boyutu

}

public void TablariAyarla () {   //Kaç tab olması isteniyorsa burda ve manifest dosyasında okdar tanımlanmalı.
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();     
    Log.w("mainactivity", "200 ");

    TabSpec tabspec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Duyurular");
    Log.w("mainactivity", "201 ");
    tabspec1.setIndicator("Duyuru");
    Log.w("mainactivity", "202 ");
    Intent tab1Intent = new Intent(this, duyurular.class);
    Log.w("mainactivity", "203 ");
    tabspec1.setContent(tab1Intent);
    Log.w("mainactivity", "204 ");

    TabSpec tabspec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Yemek Listesi");
    tabspec2.setIndicator("Yemekhane");
    Intent tab2Intent = new Intent(this, yemekListesi.class);
    tabspec2.setContent(tab2Intent);


    TabSpec tabspec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Konumunuz");
    tabspec3.setIndicator("Konum");
    Intent tab3Intent = new Intent(this, konumunuz.class);
    tabspec3.setContent(tab3Intent);

    TabSpec tabspec4 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Dahililer");
    tabspec4.setIndicator("Rehber");
    Intent tab4Intent = new Intent(this, telefon_rehberi.class);
    tabspec4.setContent(tab4Intent);
    Log.w("mainactivity", "404");
    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(tabspec1); 
    tabHost.addTab(tabspec2); 
    tabHost.addTab(tabspec3); 
    tabHost.addTab(tabspec4); 
    Log.w("mainactivity", "500 ");
}
```

**duyurular.java (first tabs's java)****

```
public class duyurular extends Activity {
static final int DIALOG_ERROR_CONNECTION = 1;
static final int YANLIS_VERI_GIRISI = 2;
static final int CIKIS_YAP = 3;
static final int ILETISIM = 4;
static JSONObject tmp;
static JSONArray jArrayDuyurular;
static String responseBody,rehberResponse,birimlerResponse = null;
static ArrayList<String>deneme = null;
static ArrayList<DuyurularSinifi> duyuruArray = new ArrayList<DuyurularSinifi>();
static View row=null;
int save = -1;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.duyurular);
    Log.w("duyurular.java", "girdiiii222");
     final ListView listwiev1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {

            try {
                Log.w("duyurular.java", "girdiiii");
//  2.3 için kaldırıdldı
        //       ColorDrawable divcolor = new ColorDrawable(R.color.DarkOrange1);    //itemlar arası ayırıcı çizgi
        //          listwiev1.setDivider(divcolor);
        //          listwiev1.setDividerHeight(2);                  
                 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    Log.i("versiyona bakıldı","3.1 den küçük");
                 }else{
                            listwiev1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.ubsacikmavi);   
                    };
                    responseBody=Giris.responseBody;
                    rehberResponse=Giris.rehberResponse;
                    birimlerResponse=Giris.birimlerResponse;;

                        if (responseBody != "") { // Json alındı
                            Log.w("duyurular.java", "girdiiii");
                            jArrayDuyurular = new JSONArray(responseBody);
                        //  System.out.println(responseBody);
                            JSONBol();

                        } else {
                            hataver("Veri alınırken hata oluştu");
                        }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("tab1", "250 ");
                e.printStackTrace();
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }
        }).start();

    listwiev1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {   //listview tıklanınca arka plan rengi ayarı
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {

            //  listwiev1.getChildAt(myItemInt).setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
            // Log.w("deneme",( Long.toString(listwiev1.getSelectedItemId())));
            /*  if (listwiev1.getSelectedItemPosition() == -1 ){  //) || myItemInt == 1){
                  listwiev1.getChildAt(myItemInt).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tabmavisi));//  Color.parseColor("#CAA48A"));

              }*/

            //  String selectedFromList =listwiev1.getAdapter().getItem(myItemInt).toString();
              String url=duyuruArray.get(myItemInt).geturl();           //duyurularla ilgili url yi arraydan alma

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);       

          }
    }); 

}
```

**activty_main.xml****

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:dividerPadding="2dp"
        android:showDividers="middle" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

***duyurular.xml (first tab)***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tabmavisi"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Üniversite Duyuruları"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="normal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/ubsacikmavi"
        android:divider="?android:attr/listDividerAlertDialog"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp" >

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

***product_row.xml (row for listview)***

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tabmavisi"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Üniversite Duyuruları"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="normal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/ubsacikmavi"
        android:divider="?android:attr/listDividerAlertDialog"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp" >

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

***this my logcat output***

```
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start       activity ComponentInfo{nevsehir.portal/portal.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nevsehir.portal/portal.duyurular}:  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class  android.widget.ListView
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nevsehir.portal/portal.duyurular}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1487)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at portal.MainActivity.TablariAyarla(MainActivity.java:136)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at portal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    ... 11 more
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at portal.duyurular.onCreate(duyurular.java:67)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    ... 21 more
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    ... 33 more
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010305 a=-1}
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:175)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:159)
          08-28 07:21:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(723):    ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at list line:

> Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or
>   path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010305 a=-1}

The definition `"@color/ubsacikmavi` doesn't seem to be a drawable though it has to be one (see documentation of [`android:background`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground))

Comment: it's very complicate. i suppose the problem from the listview's divider .i choosen "android:divider="?android:attr/listDividerAlertDialog" but now change "android:divider="?android:attr/listDivider" .thank you

Comment: Oh yes, `android:divider` has to be a drawable as well (as per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:divider); why don't you use simply a color plus `android:dividerHeight`? Or you could use shapes as well (check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)